# How to Debug applications on Device using QtCreator

Tags: debugging, qt, symbian, qt-creator, nokia

I am new to symbian development and want to debug applications running on my Nokia N8 device.

I installed CODA into my device, but I dont know how to debug applications running on it.

Answer (score 1):

[Qt Creator Manual](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-snapshot/index.html) explains how to debug your application on your device in section called [Debugging](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-snapshot/creator-debugging.html).